# Access the EPartService after an RCP application has initialized

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

After my application initialized, I'm trying to automatically create a part within a part stack. I need the EPartService for this but I can't think of any way to properly get a hold of this service.

I've tried using the LifeCycle management to get the current IEclipseContext. However, whenever I try to access the service using the context, it's not found.

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: What do you mean by initialized? I have created one example for opening part using application model and command-handler without LifeCycle management classes, [Here](https://milanardeshana.wordpress.com/2016/01/23/open-a-view-using-command-and-handler-in-e4-application/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to inject the `EPartService` in any of the defined methods in your life cycle class. However you won't be able to show a part until the application startup is complete. So use the App Startup Complete event, by adding a method like this to the life cycle class:

```java
@Optional
@Inject
public void appStartupComplete(@UIEventTopic(UIEvents.UILifeCycle.APP_STARTUP_COMPLETE)  Event event,
                               EPartService partService)
{
  ....
}
```